# Removing <b> tag in javascript

Tags: javascript

Actually I've found a similar questions and neither of the answers helped me.
Could someone please help me figuring out how to remove `<b>` from a variable in js?

What I have is the following:
`var p_name_original = $(this).find('td#p_name').html();`
`alert(p_name_original);`

which returnes some text in bold, like `<b>text</b>`.
How to remove this `<b>` and `</b>` from p_name_original? It'd be much better if I could remote it while assigning the value to p_name_original.

Thanks in advance,
AshotAr.

Comment: You could do `alert(p_name_original.innerHTML);`

Comment: Didn't help, it alerts "Undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple: change `.html()` to `.text()`

Answer (score 1):

If there are only `<b>` Tags use this:

```
function strip(html)
{
var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
tmp.innerHTML = html;
return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText;
}
```

If there are others to:

```
function strip(html)
{
html = html.replace(/<b>/g, "");
html = html.replace(/<\/b>/g, "");
return html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var p_name_original = $(this).find('td#p_name>b').html();
 alert(p_name_original);
```